# Invalid Attempt To Read Data when no Data is Present

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Values Not Being Stored to Database      

cmd = new SqlCommand("ImportExcel", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserCategory", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.UserCategory;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.CompanyName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrimaryContact", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.PrimaryContact;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.Title;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.FirstName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.LastName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LeadIndustryType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.IndustruType;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupplierService", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = imp.ServiceCategory;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Designation", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.Designation;
              //  cmd.Parameters.Add("@AnnualRevenue", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ContactsObj.AnnualRevenue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneCountryCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.PhoneCountryCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.PhoneNumber;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MobileCountryCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.MobileCountryCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MobileNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.MobileNumber;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.Email;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imp.EmailOption))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailOption", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = imp.EmailOption;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailOption", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imp.OfferAlertReceive))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OfferAlertReceive", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = imp.OfferAlertReceive;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OfferAlertReceive", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@SecondaryEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.SecondaryEmail;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SkypeID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value =imp.SkypeID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fax", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.Fax;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Website", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.Website;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PresentAddressLine1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value =imp.PresentAddressLine1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PresentAddressLine2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value =imp.PresentAddressLine2;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PresentCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value =imp.PresentCity;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PresentState", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.PresentState;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PresentCountry", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.PresentCountry;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PresentZipCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.PresentZipCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PermanentAddressLine1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.PermanentAddressLine1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PermanentAddressLine2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.PermanentAddressLine2;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PermanentCity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = imp.PermanentCity;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PermanentState", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.PermanentState;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imp.PermanentCountry))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PermanentCountry", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.PermanentCountry;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PermanentCountry", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PermanentZipCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.PermanentZipCode;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imp.GroupName))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OfferAlertType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.OfferAlertType;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OfferAlertType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(imp.GroupName))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroupName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.GroupName;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroupName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LeadSource",SqlDbType.NVarChar,100).Value=imp.LeadSource;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = imp.Description;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = imp.CreatedBy;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ip", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = imp.ip;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();               
                    //dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    string st = string.Empty;
                    while (dr1.Read())
                    {
                         st = dr1[0].ToString();
                    }

              st = dr1[0].ToString();
                return st;
```

Comment: if data is not there you cannot do `st = dr1[0].ToString();` outside while loop

Comment: sqldatareader has rows always return false

Comment: i have Executed it outside the While Loop TOO but Same Error is Displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line after your `while` loop:-

```
st = dr1[0].ToString();
```

You need to call the `Read()` method to actually read the date from `DataReader` object.

Also, it would be better if you will wrap your code within `using` block:-

```
using (SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (dr1.Read())
   {
       st = dr1[0].ToString(); //With Index
       st = dr1["ColumnName"].ToString(); //With Column Name
   }
}
```

**Update:**
Based on your comment, this is an Insert SP and you were trying to read the return value so you can't use `SqlDataReader`, if you want to return whether SP successfully inserted data, you can return status code like `1` for `successfull insertion` & `0` for failure or something. You can then read this return code like this:-

```
SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("StatusCd", SqlDbType.Int);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int statusCode = (int)returnParameter.Value;
```

But if you want to return a text like you have mentioned `Successfully Inserted`, you need to add that as `Output parameter` because SQL can only return interger values, you can then retrieve this output value as:-

```
SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.Int);
output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(output);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
st = output.Value.ToString();
```

Here, @code will be the ouput parameter in your SP, which you'll set as: `SET @code = 'Insert successfull'`.

Comment: Bro not Clear . Could u explain

Comment: @user2392626 - What I suspected was, from your code after `While` loop, you are again calling `st = dr1[0].ToString();` so this must be the cause of exception. But, just read your comment that you have just added it fro testing purpose, is that so?

Comment: i Removed That Too but Its Not WOrking

Comment: @user2392626 - Okay. Are you sure this SP is returning data? Please run `SQL Profiler` and check, also please try with actual column name returned instead of index once. Have updated the Column Name code.

Comment: i have Checked its SP Retuning Value . But the Reader Is not Reading The Data to insert it

Comment: Okay! Tell me what this SP is returning? A single value? Is that a insert SP?

Comment: SP Return Value as message as Successfully Inserted

Comment: @user2392626 - Please check my update, you are doing it the wrong way.